# Page 99 of Hindry's Arithmetics, follows from exact sequence that $\text{N}(IJ) = \text{N}(J)\text{card}(J/IJ)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Considering the following excerpt from page 98-99 of Hindry's *Arithmetics*.

[image]
[image]

Why does it follow from the exact sequence that $\text{N}(IJ) = \text{N}(J)\text{card}(J/IJ)$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, Marc Hindry was my teacher, do you have a copy of this book? sounds great

Answer (score 1):

In an exact sequence 
$$0\to A\to B\to C\to 0 $$of abelian groups we have $|B|=|A|\cdot |C|$.